# Warning for embedding Git Repository even though I'm using Submodules

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I'm trying to figure out how Git Submodules work. I read a lot of documentation online and managed to add submodules to my project. This seems to work but for some reason I keep getting this warning in my terminal:

```
warning: adding embedded git repository: web/modules/custom/svds_adminmenu
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> web/modules/custom/svds_adminmenu
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached web/modules/custom/svds_adminmenu
hint: 
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

I find this strange because the svds_adminmenu repository is the one I added as submodule. So why is it still giving me this warning.

What I did to get this is the following:

```
git clone path/repo.git
```

And after this I used the following

```
git submodules update --init
```

I got this warning in the terminal when I made changes to the .gitignore file and did the following:

```
git rm -r --cached
git add --all
git commit -m '.gitignore changed'
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is normally seen for a nested Git repository with no commit checked out (unborn branch, or freshly created without any commit)

Git 2.22 (Q2 2019) will be more explicit about this situation:

See [commit f937bc2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f937bc2f86ba2c2956b4228bd2386aaafc9afe83), [commit b228270](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b22827045e0b6c2ae1b12be2820cdc4b7f750895), [commit e138111](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e13811189bbd6b8672e3359f25c1e10f0c9b3c20) (09 Apr 2019) by [Kyle Meyer (`kyleam`)](https://github.com/kyleam).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4ab701b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ab701b2eec46ab5cbfe8c9732897e5d100184d8), 08 May 2019)</sup>

> ### `add`: error appropriately on repository with no commits
>
> The previous commit made '`git add`' abort when given a repository that doesn't have a commit checked out.
>   However, the output upon failure isn't appropriate:
>
> ```
> % git add repo
> warning: adding embedded git repository: repo
> hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
> hint: [...]
> error: unable to index file 'repo/'
> fatal: adding files failed
> ```
>
> The hint doesn't apply in this case, and the error message doesn't tell the user why 'repo' couldn't be added to the index.
>
> Provide better output by teaching `add_to_index()` to error when given a git directory where HEAD can't be resolved.
>   To avoid the embedded repository warning and hint, call `check_embedded_repo()` only after `add_file_to_index()` succeeds because, in general, its output doesn't make sense if adding to the index fails.

You will now see:

```
'<nested repo folder' does not have a commit checked out
fatal: adding files failed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the .git folder in the child folder and then track it back using

```
git add the_child_folder
git commit -m 'commit message'
```